# Trying to understand how domains work in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, security, dns, loader, sandbox

So, these past few days I had to deal with something like:

- allowSecurityDomain
- contentLoaderInfo
- appDomain
- securitySandbox
- etc

it "seems" like these things belong to the same bag.

So, is there a tutorial/guide/manual to fully understand how these security related stuff work?, my app is running now but, I have that "void" in my beign that screams: "yeah sure, it works but you didnt understand anything lol".

Thx :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on an app right now that uses most of these features and I found this document pretty helpful:

[White paper: Adobe Flash Player 10 security](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_player10_security_wp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here I got you a few posts you can read for more info on what you're asking ! I hope it helps.

[Remote content loading in AS3](http://ahatch.com/log/2009/02/remote-content-loading-in-as3-phew/)

[ApplicationDomain](http://blogs.adobe.com/rgonzalez/2006/06/applicationdomain.html)

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). Please [don't just post a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer), also provide content directly in your post. An answer consisting of just a link to your blog might be considered spam, you should at least summarize the main point (and then linking to your blog for more details is fine).